# JavaFX Application won't start on OSX after Java update: Platform: Mac OS X - not available: com.sun.prism.es2.MacGLFactory

Tags: java, macos, javafx, platform

Since the last update of Java, I can't start my JavaFX Application on Mac OS X. It still works on a Windows VM and a Ubuntu 13.04 Maschine. Direct after launch it gives me this Exception:

```
GLFactory.static - Platform: Mac OS X - not available: com.sun.prism.es2.MacGLFactory
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.prism.es2.MacGLFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    at com.sun.prism.es2.GLFactory$1.run(GLFactory.java:70) at com.sun.prism.es2.GLFactory$1.run(GLFactory.java:70)
    at com.sun.prism.es2.GLFactory$1.run(GLFactory.java:70)
    at com.sun.prism.es2.GLFactory$1.run(GLFactory.java:64)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.prism.es2.GLFactory.<clinit>(GLFactory.java:64)
    at com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline.<clinit>(ES2Pipeline.java:58)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    at com.sun.prism.GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline(GraphicsPipeline.java:150)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:72)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:107)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: I have the same problem running 10.8.5 with Java version "1.7.0_45"

Comment: I have installed the Java8 JDK an it works.